# Assert Dynamic Classes Tescafe and vue-virtual-scroll-list

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

Case:
New to testcafe and I would appreciate if someone could help.

I want to loop through a list of buttons with dynamic classes, click them and check if the class has changed.

I fail to loop and assert that the classes has changed.
(The element that matches the specified selector is not visible.)

```
fixture`The Loop`.beforeEach(async (t) => {
  await t.useRole(loginUser);
})
test("Summary List check marks", async (t) => {

  // const markStop = Selector('div.btn-group-y').find('[data-attribute="markStopBtn"]')
  await t.click(selector.driverReadyBtn);

  let markStopBtn = await selector.markStopBtn
  let markStopBtnCount = await markStopBtn.count;

  for(let i=0; i < markStopBtnCount; i++){
    if(markStopBtn.nth(i).exists && markStopBtn.nth(i).visible) {
      await t
      .click(markStopBtn.nth(i))
      // .expect(markStopBtn.withAttribute('class', 'btn-primary').exists).ok()
    }
  }
});



File.Vue///
          <div
              data-attribute="markStopBtn"
              :class="[
                'btn btn-icon btn-secondary-outline p-4',
                {
                  ['btn-primary']: completed,
                  ['btn-cancelled']: issued,
                  ['btn-blueDark-inverse']: !issued && !completed,
                },
              ]"
              @click="clickCompleteStop"
            >
```

Trows Error
(The element that matches the specified selector is not visible.)

```
 |    if(markStopBtn.nth(i).exists && markStopBtn.nth(i).visible) {
         23 |      await t
       > 24 |      .click(markStopBtn.nth(i))
         25 |      // .expect(markStopBtn.withAttribute('class', 'btn-primary').exists).ok()
         26 |    }
```

Comment: Please check on the page that the buttons don't have the `visibility: hidden` or `display: none` properties, their `clientWidth` and `clientHeight` property values are more than zero, and all the buttons can be seen in the viewport (if not, then changing the viewport using the [t.resizeWindow](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/test-api/testcontroller/resizewindow.html) method can be helpful).

Comment: If the issue persists, I recommend you create a [bug report](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?template=bug-report.md) with your full page source code so the TestCafe team can investigate it more deeply.